# IP to use in configs that point to localhost of computer 1 when in computer 2

Tags: ip, webserver

It's really hard to find the right wordings for this, but I'll try;

I'm setting up configs for my just-for-fun locally-hosted server and I came across a problem. Part of the config is requesting for the IP to use when executing a script for downloading an item:

```
  'script_url' => 'http://localhost/fsp/',
```

Although correct for me, this will cause a loop-back for the client when accessing said script, redirecting them from let's say, `192.168.43.1/phpfilehere.php` to `localhost/phpfilehere.php`

Now comes the question, I'm using my phone as a server (Samsung) and I cant really configure my IP to be static when hosting the hotspot, which IP should I use?

Comment: Have you tried 127.0.0.1, which is the same as localhost

Answer (score 0):

Localhost is always localhost.
Localhost is the loopback to the calling computer.

What you can do, is read the IP of the current computer, get the subnet mask and from there scan your IP block for the right computer.

---

For example:

Let's say you have the following IP: *192.168.1.32/24*

The subnet mask would be *255.255.255.0* - this means you have **253** IP addresses which could potentially be your web server.

*192.168.1.0* is the network address, this is where your router is located on the network (or the phone in your case).

*192.168.1.255* is the broadcast address. Sending packets to this address will send them to each and every device on the network.

Knowing this information, you could either brute-force it and send your data to everyone on the network and you'll risk others seeing potentially trippy packets - or you can scan the network, IP by IP and then look for specific open ports.

Let's say your web server listens to the IP *192.168.1.230*:*8000*.

You'd just have to scan each IP and check if the port 8000 is open.

If it is, you've likely found your server and can now use that address to send your packets.

---

Note that this is NOT a fool-proof method, and it probably isn't even the best or most efficient. 
I'm just saying what you could do in this situation, as you (presumably) can't set a static IP.

Another method might be a simple DNS service running on the phone which would resolve a domain (e.g.: mytest.serv) to the IP of the server.